# iOS App, fetch text content

Tags: ios, xcode, text, content-management-system, web-hosting

For an app I will be building, I will need the ability to remotely alter and update the text that is displayed on a page of the app.

Is there any way to get the UI Text View to fetch text from a .txt file which is hosted on a server? If not what methods would you suggest for displaying external text?

Thanks,
Dylan

Answer (score 1):

NSString *text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

textView.text = text;

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what you mean by .txt file hosted on a server?

You could use a NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection to create an HTTP GET request and download a .txt file from a server, then store it in the text property on your UITextView.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someserver.com/file.txt"]];

    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    self.textView.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: What I mean was: If I created a .txt file on my computer and then stored this on a server (some kind of hosting plan). I could then get a url which would display the text document that could be accessed via the UItextView in the app. I want to be able to update the text content of my app and so though that if I could just update a .txt file which is stored on the server, then the app would automatically pull in the newest (current) version of it. Hope this makes some sense! Dylan